# Google ReCaptcha Always Return False after domain transfer

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I moved my website and domain to a new hoster and since then Google Recaptcha has stopped working.

I haven't changed anything in the code and the domain has also remained the same.

This is my PHP code to check the verification it has worked for years

```
<?php
    $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => '************************',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "<strong>Captcha Check Fail</strong> Bitte versuche es nocheinmal." }';
    } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
        
    }
?>
```

this is a finished script from the internet, but it doesn't work either. I've tried several finished scripts but none of them work

```
<script src="https://google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<form action="" method="POST" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 497px;">
    <div style="margin-left: 48px;"><b> Registration Form </b><br><br></div>
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br><br></div>
    <div>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /><br><br></div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="******************"></div><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'SUBMIT'){
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
  {
        $secret = '*********************';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->true)
        { ?>
<div style="color: limegreen;"><b>Your contact request have submitted successfully.</b></div>
        <?php }
        else
        {?>
            <div style="color: red;"><b>Robot verification failed, please try again.</b></div>
        <?php }
   }else{?>
       <div style="color: red;"><b>Please do the robot verification.</b></div>
   <?php }
 }
?>
```

Of course I have deleted the Recaptcha account several times and generated new tokens, but nothing changes. can it also be due to the hoster? are there any PHP settings that prevent recapatcha? the server runs on PHP 7.4 and the domain has an SSL certificate from lets encrypt.

thank you for your help

Comment: When you call `json_decode` it will always return false if it's unable to parse the JSON. Try outputting what you're getting back before trying to decode it to see if that gives you a clue. Alternatively, switch to using `curl` which can get you a lot more info with `curl_getinfo`. Could it be your host? Yes. Some hosts will not allow outbound requests or have special ways you are required to do it.

Comment: Have you checked your new server has allow_url_fopen enabled in the php.ini file?
You can use the phpinfo() command and search the output for the value.

Comment: Thanks @Steve that's was the problem allow_url_fopen was not enabled Thank you

Comment: Glad that helped @Azalen - I've popped the solution in as an answer in case anyone else stumbles across this post with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer here for anyone else seeking similar advice.

The issue was that the new host didn't have `allow_url_fopen` enabled in the PHP configuration.

This can be checked by searching the output of a `phpinfo();` call.

Enabling `allow_url_fopen` can usually be achieved by editing your php.ini file, making changes in php settings in cPanel or Plesk or by contacting your hosting provider's support team.

`file_get_contents` requires `allow_url_fopen`.